# App engine Backend won't Build

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I recently updated Eclipse GAE plug-in and now my mobile application backend won't build because it isn't configured as a web application. Has anyone seen this issue and, if so, what is the solution to it? I assume it is a setting but I haven't figured out where

Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: 'myProjectTitle' is not configured as a web application
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.WebAppUtilities.verifyIsWebApp(WebAppUtilities.java:370)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.resources.GaeProject.getXmlFile(GaeProject.java:310)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.resources.GaeProject.getAppEngineWebXml(GaeProject.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.resources.GaeProject.getAppId(GaeProject.java:209)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.HandleGaeProjectChange.createSwarmServiceCreator(HandleGaeProjectChange.java:63)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.HandleGaeProjectChange.gaeProjectRebuilt(HandleGaeProjectChange.java:41)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.CloudEndpointsBuilder.build(CloudEndpointsBuilder.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost embarrassed to say this but this was the solution to my issue:

I removed Google App Engine from my App's Build path (I don't recall putting it in), cleaned/ rebuilt it, then I went to the error log and deleted the error. Just control-click delete...

Lacing up for a few laps, if anyone comes across this issue, it could be an eclipse error or something but I am not sure.